# Unable to use program with MySQL

Tags: mysql

At work I use a program that doesnt exist anymore on the internet called Eclick v2 by Okeymedia. It's Windows based, and I copied all files and configuration documents from the work computer to my home PC via USB.

[It wanted to use MySQL to connect to a database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEZla.png), so I've installed Xampp and have run apache & mysql. On phpmyadmin, I [created a database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hnda6.png) called `okeymedia2` per the config file, and created a user on phpmyadmin called `eclick`. This didn't work, so I repeated this using `'eclick'@'localhost'`. Still nothing.

It gives me [this error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCHd8.png) when trying to run the exe.

Any advice is really appreciated in getting this program to run.

Answer (score 0):

I would try adding privileges to `%`, then:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON okeymedia2.* TO `eclick`@`%` IDENTIFIED BY 'your-password';
```